# iTextSharp EXCEL output

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using the following code to output data from a number of tables in my database to an excel document.

```
Protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

string strQuery = "SELECT s.Story, s.StoryCategoryID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 
s.CreationDate, 103) AS CreationDate, m.CompanyRole, af.Name FROM Story s INNER JOIN    
ProjectIterationMember pm ON pm.ProjectIterationMemberID = s.ProjectIterationMemberID 
INNER JOIN Iterations i ON i.ProjectIterationID = pm.ProjectIterationID INNER JOIN 
Member m ON m.MemberID = pm.MemberID INNER JOIN ProjectStoryFactors psf ON psf.StoryID = 
s.StoryID INNER JOIN AgileFactors af ON af.AgileFactorID = psf.AgileFactorID WHERE 
i.ProjectID = '" + proj_id + "'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=RetroCloud" +  
DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{

   GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
}
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Story | StoryCategoryID | CreationDate | CompanyRole | Name

negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Project Duration
negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Team Size
negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Process
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Workspace Layout
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Organisational and Reporting Structure
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Process
```

What I would like to do is 3 things. Many thanks for your help!

1) Change the header names which are clearly coming from the database fields (ie. from StoryCategoryID to Story Type),
2) For StoryCategoryID, if 1 is retrieved - display 'Negative' and if 0 is retrieved - display 'Positive' instead.
3) Have the output in the following format:

```
Story | Story Type | Creation Date | Company Role | Tag 1 | Tag 2 | Tag 3

negative iii | 1 | 21/02/2011 | Business Analyst | Project Duration | Team Size | Process
negative ccc | 1 | 22/02/2011 | Admin | Workspace Layout | Organisational | Process
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the column names of the data table. Use `foreach(DataColumn col in dt.Columns)` then use `col.ColumnName`

You can access and modify the data for the specific column for your criteria using `(Convert.ToInt16(col[n]) != 1)? "Positive" : "Negative"` inside a loop. Use `dt.Rows.Count` for the loop's condition.

Hope this helps.

You can use this inside the `foreach` loop:

```
if (col.ColumnName == "StoryCategoryId") //Or "Story Type"
for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < table.Rows.Count; rowCount++)
{
    col[rowCount] = (Convert.ToInt16(col[rowCount]) == 0) ? "Positive" : "Negative";
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how to modify the column data using the loop? Thanks! I'd like to get the positive, negative bit working :)